# How to change the saturation and overlay of a sprite in Godot

Tags: colors, sprite, godot, gdscript

I have been planning to change my sprite to a bit darker color through changing saturation and hue values. But it seems very tricky to do so as the Godot modules only talk about changing the color of a sprite though the `modulate` option like this:

```
node.modulate= Color(0, 50, 2,0.5)
```

Doing so is changing the entire sprite to a new color whereas **I just want to make the existing colors to a bit darker color** the way we do in Photoshop using "Curves" or "Levels" - but not as refined. Any rudimentary method would also help.

Currently, I can only do "Color Overlay" without changing the opacity. **Any method of adding a color overlay with opacity change**  would be helpful as long as it doesn't change the opacity of the entire sprite but just the overlay color.

I am working on a 2D game with imported PNG Sprites. If any more information is required, I'll be happy to provide it.

Additional Information -

What my sprite looks like

[image]

I want to make it darker through code twice like this -

[image]  [image]

By doing node.modulate= Color(0.0, 0.0, 0.0,1) it becomes like this - 
[image]

The reason why I'm avoiding to do this manually because I have too many sprites and doing this for all of them will be tedious.

Comment: Can you post an example image of the effect you want? Modulate is a multiplication operation where if you want the sprite a little darker you set the modulation color closer to black but leave alpha at 1: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0).

Comment: When I modulate to (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), the entire sprite becomes black. I am extending this question with more details and visual references.

Comment: Okay, awesome. Thanks for adding the visuals. I'll post an answer with examples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: Example color difference image]

Here's two examples of how you can darken a sprite via code.

The first method is by using `self_modulate`. Modulation is calculated by multiplying the modulation value by texture color value. This shows that modulation of `(1, 1, 1, 1)` is the same as the original texture. A modulation of `(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)` halves the texture color making it darker like  it has a half opacity black overlay.

```
# On a node that extends CanvasItem
self_modulate = Color(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0)
```

The second method is to subtract the texture value by a constant. This creates a texture that's more saturated but darker.

The shader code:

```
shader_type canvas_item;

uniform float difference: hint_range(0.0, 1.0) = 0.0;

void fragment() {
    vec4 tex = texture(TEXTURE, UV);
    COLOR.rgb = tex.rgb - vec3(difference);
    COLOR.a = tex.a;
}
```

The other code:

```
# On a node that extends CanvasItem
material.set_shader_param('difference', 0.3)
```

---

These effects can be combined to produce the desired result. Play around with the shader to produce a better result.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Shaders seem to be the solution! Sorry for not choosing it as the correct answer sooner.